# SQL query for DATA AND TIME field minus FIVE hours

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm creating reports from database where I have to select Created date with time from database but in my databse **TIME AND DATE** is different then actually created time. It's **5 HOURS more** then actual created time.

How Can I select field with minus 5 hours .?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT `field` - INTERVAL 5 HOUR FROM `your_table`
```